# R: timeseries loop

Tags: r, loops, time-series

I have five years of monthly timeseries data.

The `month_id` represents the number of the month since the start of the data.

The data are from `July, 2016 to June, 2021`.

**What I want to do?**

I need to repeat the data '60 months' five times (25 years into the future) and assign the new dates from July, 2021 onwards and continue the month_ids from the max month_id in the current data. This means July, 2021 should be 385 and so on.

**What I did?**

```
library(tidyverse)

month_min <- min(df5yrs$month_id)
month_max <- max(df5yrs$month_id)

date_min <- min(df5yrs$date)
date_max <- max(df5yrs$date)

df5yrs <- df5yrs %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(month_id = month_id - sp_min)

repeat_no <- 5

for(i in 1:repeat_no){
  
  df_i <- df5yrs %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(month_id = month_max + month_id ) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(date = ymd(date) + years(5)) 
  
  
  if(i==1){df_25yrs <- df_i}
  else{
    
    df_25yrs <- df_25yrs %>%
      dplyr::mutate(date = ymd(date)+years(5)) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(month_id = month_id + (5*12)) 

    df_25yrs <- bind_rows(df_25yrs, df_i) 
    month_max <- max(df_25yrs$month_id)
    date_max <- max(df_25yrs$date) 
    print(paste(min(df_i$month_id),max(df_i$month_id)))
  }
}
```

**Error**

The script above works fine is I'm repeating the data two times only. However, there is an issue with the month_id if I'm repeating it 5 times. For example, the month_id for `July, 2021` is `625` while it should be `385`.

How can I fix this error?

**Data**

```
structure(list(station_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("station 1", "station 3"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 
    17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 
    17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 
    17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 
    17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 
    18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 
    18536, 18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18687, 18718, 18748, 18779, 
    17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 
    17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 
    17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 
    18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 
    18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18687, 
    18718, 18748, 18779), class = "Date"), month_id = c(325, 
    326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 
    338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 
    350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 
    362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 
    374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 337, 
    338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 
    350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 
    362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 
    374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384), value = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.01, 0, 825.01, 2513.11, 3072.3, 1122.68, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 188.57, 779.06, 2252.24, 2054.66, 0.06, 1149.09, 
    337.67, 295.36, 0.01, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 26.8, 159.14, 0.01, 
    1246.05, 1682.93, 116.88, 80.86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 1583.3, 
    1548.98, 1500.02, 1975.47, 1609.04, 277.4, 27.11, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 353.89, 217.12, 1333.62, 1714.97, 937.42, 106.76, 0, 0, 
    0, 34.27, 45.13, 42.26, 45.13, 52.72, 62.82, 68.28, 54.22, 
    35.66, 49.48, 34.91, 33.49, 43.65, 39.11, 42.71, 59.7, 56.43, 
    72.88, 83.56, 67.46, 71.63, 58.89, 13.48, 8.31, 27.74, 78, 
    33.05, 45.79, 47.57, 52.59, 70.26, 67.91, 65.92, 65.96, 46.99, 
    44.01, 45.48, 46.99, 44.01, 46.99, 38.47, 33.4, 68.65, 41.24, 
    34.46, 24.8, 28.13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-108L))
```

Comment: In your example data, `"station 1"` starts in 2016 but `"station 2"` starts in 2017. Is this intentional? If so, please edit your question to make clearer how this should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re one the right track with your approach. This solutions makes copies of `df5yrs`, adding 5 years * iteration number to year and month values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

repeat_no <- 5
df25yrs <- map(
  seq(repeat_no),
  \(i) mutate(df5yrs, date = date + (years(5) * i), month_id = month_id + (60 * i))
)

bind_rows(df5yrs, df25yrs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have 60 months for each station. I start by adding fake data for the missing 12 months, like this:

```
df = bind_rows(df, df %>% filter(station_id == "station 1", month_id<337) %>% mutate(station_id = "station 3", value= sample(df$value,12))) %>% arrange(station_id, month_id)
```

Now, once the data are complete, you can replicate the entire data frame, and then replace the `date` and `month_id` columns:

```
df %>%
  group_by(station_id) %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(),times=5)) %>% 
  mutate(
    date = seq.Date(min(date), by = "month", length.out=n()),
    month_id = seq(min(month_id), by=1, length.out=n())
  )
```

Output:

```
   station_id date       month_id   value
   <chr>      <date>        <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 station 1  2016-07-01      325    0   
 2 station 1  2016-08-01      326    0   
 3 station 1  2016-09-01      327    0   
 4 station 1  2016-10-01      328    0.01
 5 station 1  2016-11-01      329    0   
 6 station 1  2016-12-01      330  825.  
 7 station 1  2017-01-01      331 2513.  
 8 station 1  2017-02-01      332 3072.  
 9 station 1  2017-03-01      333 1123.  
10 station 1  2017-04-01      334    0   
# … with 590 more rows
```

Notice that this does replicate the data; for example, examine July 1st for years 2016, 21, 26, 31 and 36:

```
   station_id date       month_id value
   <chr>      <date>        <dbl> <dbl>
 1 station 1  2016-07-01      325    0 
 2 station 1  2021-07-01      385    0 
 3 station 1  2026-07-01      445    0 
 4 station 1  2031-07-01      505    0 
 5 station 1  2036-07-01      565    0 
 6 station 3  2016-07-01      325  338.
 7 station 3  2021-07-01      385  338.
 8 station 3  2026-07-01      445  338.
 9 station 3  2031-07-01      505  338.
10 station 3  2036-07-01      565  338.
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems the results are not accurate. The values for July 2021, 2026 and 2031, 2036, 2041 and 2046 should be the same. This is not the case.

Comment: it is the same for station 1, but you have an issue with your second station.. there are only four years of data.. What should the values be?